# Receiving non Null-Terminated data in Python Ctypes callback

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm Writing a Python ctypes wrapper for a DLL.

When an event occurs, the DLL attempts to call a callback function with the following prototype:

```
void Function(u8 *Data, u16 Length)
```

Essentially, it gives us a pointer to a buffer of raw data, and a length of that buffer.

I'm trying to find a method of receving and processing this data in my python code.

If I declare the ctypes function type as a char pointer:

```
TX_CALLBACK_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p, c_int)
```

then the data is treated as a null terminated string, and I get truncated data if any 0x00 bytes exist in the buffer.

If I declare the ctypes function type as a void pointer:

```
TX_CALLBACK_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_int)
```

then I get a long integer value, which I assume is the address of the raw data - but I don't know how to retrieve the data to use it in Python.

If I declare the ctypes function type as a POINTER to char:

```
TX_CALLBACK_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(char), c_int)
```

then I get a ctypes.LP_c_char object, but I can't figure out how to access the raw data in the object.

What's the best way to access raw data in Python which is returned from a wrapped DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a buffer:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> b = ctypes.c_buffer("abc\0def", 16)
>>> b.value
'abc'
>>> b.raw
'abc\x00def\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I was using a buffer, but my I was incorrectly using .value rather than .raw.

Comment: Also note that c_buffer seems to have been deprecated in favour of create_string_buffer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data out of a `ctypes.LP_c_char` just **slice it**.

```
def processBytes(pBuffer,len):<br>
   <b>print(pBuffer[:len])</b>


CB_FUNC_TYPE = ctypes.CFUNCTION(None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char),ctypes.c_int)<br>
cb_func = CB_FUNC_TYPE(processBytes)


//Need to setup cb_func in C <br>
//In C assign your call-back function<br>
void (*c_cb_func)(char *, int) = cb_func<br>

// Call your python function from C<br>
(c_cb_func)(pBuffer,len)
```